# How to remove this citation error?

Tags: citing

*[Heydt 1989]* was intended in the PDF output.

but it's appearing as:

*[cite]cite.heydt1989identicationHeydt 1989]*

The entry in the .bib file was.

```
@article{heydt1989identification, 
title={Identification of harmonic sources by a state estimation technique}, 
author={Heydt, GT}, 
journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery}, 
volume={4}, 
number={1}, 
pages={569--576}, 
year={1989}, 
publisher={IEEE} }
```

What might be the reason of this misformatting?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Plplease elaborate it, the best with small, complete document, which show, what is going on in your case. Welcome to site!

Comment: For the citation of the bibitem (@article{heydt1989identification,
 title={Identification of harmonic sources by a state estimation technique},
 author={Heydt, GT},
 journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery},
 volume={4},
 number={1},
 pages={569--576},
 year={1989},
 publisher={IEEE}
}), intended was [Heydt 1989] in the pdf but it's appearing as [cite]cite.heydt1989identicationHeydt 1989]. How can I get the correct one?

Comment: Please add a [minimal but working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) to your question (not to a comment but into the question!). Without I would only speculate, that you've missed to run `biber` or something went wrong while the `biber` run or there is something wrong with your `\cite` command or your `bib` file. But I cannot say, whats wrong in detail.

Comment: The standard question is [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). But the output you report is very peculiar, please prepare a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that allows us to reproduce the undesired behaviour.

Comment: Any news here? Without an MWE or at least information on how you produce your citations and bibliography your question is impossible to answer. I will cote to close your question as 'unclear what you are asking' in due time if you don't edit it.